# TSQL decision statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a view that select a number of fields as you can see. The main focus of the query though is xro_roles.start_page. This field holds a start page link for a stored procedure to reference. But I have a second table that also holds some links (this table is called branches). If the dbo.people.role_id = 1 then I need it to use the branches table for the start_page column. If the role_id is not 1 then it should reference the xro_roles.start_page.

I am not to sure how to use a CASE statement in this scenario. If I am not giving enough information let me know.

Thanks

```
 SELECT dbo.people.people_id, dbo.people.role_id, dbo.people.company_id, 
           dbo.xro_roles.start_page, dbo.areas.area_id,
FROM dbo.areas RIGHT OUTER JOIN
          dbo.divisions ON dbo.areas.area_id = dbo.divisions.area_id RIGHT OUTER JOIN
          dbo.people LEFT OUTER JOIN
          dbo.xro_roles ON dbo.people.role_id = dbo.xro_roles.role_id ON dbo.divisions.division_id = dbo.people.division_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
          dbo.companies ON dbo.people.company_id = dbo.companies.company_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
          dbo.xro_time_zones ON dbo.people.time_zone_id = dbo.xro_time_zones.time_zone_id
          LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.branches ON dbo.branches.branch_id = dbo.people.division_id
WHERE (dbo.people.status_id IN (0, 1, 4))
```

Comment: can you please clean this a little so may be we can help..

Comment: Try to provide a simple query (use aliases rather than the whole object path) and keep the minimum fields for the question.

Comment: right join, right join, left join, left join, left join, left join? Is this a secret video game code, like up, down, up, down, right, left, a, b, etc?

Comment: apparently...this isn't anything I wrote, just cleaning stuff up. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `CASE WHEN` in the `SELECT` portion of the query:

```
SELECT  dbo.people.people_id
        , dbo.people.role_id
        , dbo.people.company_id
        , CASE WHEN dbo.people.role_id = 1
            THEN    dbo.branches.start_page     -- assuming the column name is "start_page"
            ELSE    dbo.xro_roles.start_page
          END AS some_field_name
        , dbo.areas.area_id
FROM    dbo.areas
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.divisions
            ON  dbo.areas.area_id = dbo.divisions.area_id
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.people
            ON  dbo.divisions.division_id = dbo.people.division_id      
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.xro_roles
            ON  dbo.people.role_id = dbo.xro_roles.role_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.companies
            ON  dbo.people.company_id = dbo.companies.company_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.xro_time_zones
            ON  dbo.people.time_zone_id = dbo.xro_time_zones.time_zone_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.branches
            ON  dbo.branches.branch_id = dbo.people.division_id
WHERE   dbo.people.status_id IN (0, 1, 4)
```

You could also use a `COALESCE` instead of a `CASE WHEN` depending on how you set up your joins, although that may not give you the desired results if `dbo.people.status_id` is not `1` in other cases:

```
SELECT  dbo.people.people_id
        , dbo.people.role_id
        , dbo.people.company_id
        , COALESCE(dbo.branches.start_page, dbo.xro_roles.start_page) AS some_field_name
        , dbo.areas.area_id
FROM    dbo.areas
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.divisions
            ON  dbo.areas.area_id = dbo.divisions.area_id
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.people
            ON  dbo.divisions.division_id = dbo.people.division_id      
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.xro_roles
            ON  dbo.people.role_id = dbo.xro_roles.role_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.companies
            ON  dbo.people.company_id = dbo.companies.company_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.xro_time_zones
            ON  dbo.people.time_zone_id = dbo.xro_time_zones.time_zone_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.branches
            ON  dbo.branches.branch_id = dbo.people.division_id
            AND dbo.people.status_id = 1    -- This JOIN may not do what you want and is included only as an example.
WHERE   dbo.people.status_id IN (0, 1, 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all clean up your sql.  Use table aliases! Don't mix left and right outer joins. Use parentheses when performing joins out of sequence joins (although in this case you can, as I have shown below, reorganize the joins so as to not need that)

assuming the field in branches table is named `start_page`, then try this: 
(third line has the case statement)

```
Select p.people_id, p.role_id, p.company_id, p.department_id, p.lang_id, 
    p.password, p.user_name, p.display_name, r.start_page, p.first_name, 
    case p.role_id when 1 then b.start_page else r.frame_start_page end startPage,, 
    p.full_name, r.role, p.security_question, 
    dbo.sp_getTimeZoneUSEstOffset(GETDATE(), z.time_zone_id) offset, 
    r.timeout, p.show_help_tips, p.currency_id, p.status_id, p.last_name, 
    p.country_id, a.region_id, a.area_id, p.group_id, d.division_id, 
    p.section_id, p.unit_id, ISNULL(d.stylesheet, c.stylesheet) stylesheet, 
    p.owner_company_id, p.owner_country_id, p.owner_division_id, p.owner_department_id, 
    ISNULL(d.logo_image_file_name, c.logo_image_file_name) logo_image_file, 
    p.subunit_id, r.role_type, p.onsite_company_id, p.onsite_division_id, 
    p.onsite_department_id, p.email_confirm, p.email_notify, c.company_type_id, 
    p.time_zone_id, c.company, p.date_updated_password, p.building_id,
    p.failed_logins, p.login_locked, c.logoff_page, p.external_id, 
    p.onsite_building_id, p.kpi_all_access KAA, p.data_entry_mode, 
    c.force_password_change, c.password_change_days,
    c.allow_password_recycle, c.login_attempts_allowed, c.custom_vocab, 
    p.team_id, p.subteam_id, p.btn_click_disable, 
    dbo.sp_getTimeZoneABR(GETDATE(), z.time_zone_id) tmz_abr
From dbo.people p 
    Left Join dbo.xro_roles r On r.role_id = p.role_id
    Left Join dbo.divisions d On d.division_id = p.division_id 
    Left Join dbo.areas a On a.area_id = d.area_id 
    Left Join dbo.companies c ON c.company_id = p.company_id 
    Left Join dbo.xro_time_zones z ON z.time_zone_id = p.time_zone_id
    Left Join dbo.branches b ON b.branch_id = p.division_id
Where p.status_id IN (0, 1, 4)
```

Comment: Are sp_getTimeZoneABR and sp_getTimeZoneUSEstOffset functions? Why do they have an sp prefix?

Comment: @Aaron, they were in original post before he edited it to simplify

Comment: Ah, OK. Well, same question for the OP. You shouldn't be using the sp_ prefix for anything, especially things that aren't procedures.

Comment: @Aaron, he mentioned that he inherited this proc from previous developers.  As I am sure you are aware, but I will add here for completeness, the `sp_` prefix is a legacy from early SQL server (maybe even from pre-SQL Server Sybase), which caused the DB engine to look in the master database as well as in the current Database, if a proc with that name did not exist in the current DB.  It stood for "System Procedure", but unfortunately, many early developers misunderstood, and assumed it meant "Stored Procedure", and used it for all their own procs as well.

Comment: Putting a proc in master, with this naming convention, allowed it to be used by all the DBs on the server.  Microsoft used this technique for their system procedures.  This is still a good technique for Individual developers for general procs that are to be used in muultiple DBs.  Other than causing the engine to look in master if it can't find the proc in the current DB, (and betraying a less than educated level of proficiency), I don't know of any other downside to this mistake.  Are there others?

Comment: I'm well aware of the history, thanks - though the `sp` actually stood for `special`, not `system procedure` (at least according to Kalen Delaney). [If you use `sp_` you will have a performance hit whether there is an equivalent object in master or not](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). And it is incredibly misleading to name a function with `sp_` because so many people use that prefix only for stored procedures. I don't think I've ever seen it used for a function before.

Comment: (Also, just a pedantic nit: `CASE` is an expression, not a statement.)

Comment: A quick read of your link I found "The performance issue comes from the fact that master might be checked for an equivalent stored procedure, depending on whether there is a local version of the procedure,"  Doesn't that mean the performance hit only comes if there is no local proc with the same name ?  ALso, if you fully quality the call `MyServer.MyDB.MySchema.sp_MyProcName`  then the proc finder  (is there aother name for this thing that searches and finds the proc??)  wouldn't look anywhere else, right?

Comment: No, did you look at the performance comparisons? When there is a local procedure with that name, the overhead is there (and if there isn't a local version of the procedure, what are we talking about? You must have wanted to call the one in master). And I didn't test a 4-part name - even if it does work, is this supposed to be justification for allowing the `sp_` prefix? Do you really want to code that way rather than just ***not use the sp_ prefix***?

Answer (score 1):

```
  (case when people.role_id=1 Then Branches.start_page 
  else xro_roles.start_page end)<ColumnName>
```